# Local web server on windows stopped being reachable by devices on the same network

Tags: webserver, windows-firewall

I use a local Python web server on my Windows machine. It’s simple, but good enough while in the static web page development stage. I just run it with something like this on my [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) command line:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

I can also access it on mobile devices on the same network, by going to my local address, e.g.: `http://192.168.1.12:8000`. All was good, until suddenly I could no longer access it on external devices, I got a “server not responding” type of message. Also, I could clearly see that when I refreshed the page on my phone, there was no `GET` request on the logs.

Immediately I tested on the local machine, and it was still working fine. This obviously smelled like a Firewall. In [Linux](https://serverfault.com/a/868196/422246), I’d know what to do, but it’s the first time I had to deal with this on Windows. This is what I’ve tried, without resolving the connection problem:

- I opened the Event Viewer but could not see any obvious logs to check
- I stopped the server (CTRL+C) and started it again on another port (5000). The Windows Firewall message popped up again asking for permission for Python3 to access the “Public network” and the “Private network”. Normally I just tick the “private network” but this time I checked both, as a troubleshooting step, in case my Wi-Fi was incorrectly being considered “public”.
- I went to Windows Firewall and temporarily shut it down on the private network.
- I installed and tried running nmap on the WSL, but it failed to run and prompted me to install the Windows version instead.
- I installed and ran the Windows version of nmap but it told me that port 5000 was open.

What is the recommended way to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Still suspecting the firewall, I tried something new, I switched off the “public network” firewall. I tested on my mobile and the page loaded as normal again! I immediately turned the firewall back on. Tested the page on my mobile once more, still fine. So, the solution was to **toggle** the public network firewall. I would make it more generic and toggle all firewall categories on Windows. And of course, I would make sure that the firewall stays on, this was a very quick operation.

I thought I’d put this here rather than *ServerFault* or *SuperUser* as it could potentially be more useful to developers, and it took a precious hour of my time. I still don’t know why it stopped working on its own in the first place. Better troubleshooting steps or suggestions are welcome, but I probably won’t be able to verify it as I don’t know how to purposely induce the issue.

Another solution that worked another time, was to delete all instances of Python 3.8 from the list of allowed apps (I don't know why Windows shows the same app multiple times) then (re)start the Python server and allow it through when the Firewall question pops up again.

Answer (score 0):

In windows firewall you may have 4 options to configure your local web server when you are creating new Inbound connections rule.

1 Program
2 Port
3 Predefined
4 Custom

Try to use port only in "TCP protocol" and the custom port.
Allow connection.
Select: all checks: domain, private and public.
Enter a name.

Thats all.